# Using a helper function with numpy.genfromtxt()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to read data into an array from file `myfile` which contains a string at the beginning which I intend to ignore. Something like this :-

```
"myfile", 1.0, 2.0, 3.0
,4.0, 5.0, 6.0
```

Here's the code :-

```
def func(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp
    line = next(fp).split(',')
    yield ','.join(line[1:])
    for line in fin:
        yield line

arr = np.genfromtxt(func('myfile'), delimiter=',')
```

I get an exception :-

```
Line #2 (got 4 columns instead of 3)
```

What I find strange is that if my data looks something like this,

```
"myfile", 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 
 ,5.0, 6.0, 7.0
```

I get

```
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
   [ nan,   4.,   5.,   6.]])
```

Could anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Is the second line `4.0, 5,0, 6,0` or `4.0, 5.0, 6.0`?

Comment: A typo. I corrected it

Comment: You still have 4 elements in the second line (`4.0`, `5.0`, `6` and `0`) -- which explains the error message.  Numpy expects each row to contain the same number of elements.  Your first row has 3 elements, your second row has 4.

Comment: Why do you iterate `fin` instead of `fp`?

Comment: @AdaXu -- After your last edit, the code works for me ... As for why the second example works -- numpy appears to be expecting 4 columns of data in your file since that's the number of elements in the first row.  When it processes the second row with less elements, it pads with `nan`.  In other words, rows need to have the same number or less columns than the first row.  If it's less, it will be padded with `nan`.

Comment: @mgilson it works for you with broken indentation, no `:` after the `with` statement, and iteration over undefined name `fin`?

Comment: @wim -- No.  I can process that input file using the same idea.  the original code is from [an answer I posted earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20964932/748858).  I suppose I was assuming that OP was actually using that...

Comment: True, I took the idea from mgilson's answer to my previous question but for some strange reason it is still not working.

Comment: Oh, right I see.  I didn't know the previous question, so your comment didn't have context

Comment: I think I know where the problem is coming from. I looked at the dataset once again and there's a leading ',' on every line except the first line. I've edited my question

Comment: For Pete's sake, this is turning into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: @wim Yeah well sorry about that. I didn't see that myself. I'll accept your answer when you edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works fine, after fixing your typos:

```
import numpy as np

def func(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        line = next(fp).split(',')
        yield ','.join(line[1:])
        for line in fp:
            yield line[1:]

print np.genfromtxt(func('myfile'), delimiter=',')
```

In `myfile`:

```
"myfile", 1.0, 2.0, 3.0
,4.0, 5.0, 6.0
```

Comment: the second line has a leading 'comma'

Comment: changed to `yield line[1:]` to chuck out those leading commas

Answer (score 0):

The leading comma on the second line is the cause of this behavior. genfromtxt expects another value there, and substitutes nan if there is none. So the second line has 4 values according to genfromtxt. Which is fine if the same applies to your first line; but genfromtxt expects a square block of input, in a row/col type format. One thing you could do is replace the string to be removed by an additional leading comma, turning strings presents into nans; if that indeed does consistently make your data square. If not, the best way to proceed heavily depends on what your data actually does look like.